# Trying to show that $\sup \{b^p:p\in Q,\;0<p<x\} = \inf\{b^q:q\in Q,\;x<q\}$

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to show that for $b>1$, $x>0$ and $x$ irrational, that $$\sup \{b^p:p\in Q,\;0<p<x\} = \inf\{b^q:q\in Q,\;x<q\}$$ I know this follows immediately if we define $b^x=\exp(x\log(b))$ and use the fact that the exponential function is strictly increasing and continuous over $\mathbb R$, but I'm not allowed to do that. In fact, I only have that $b^{m/n}=(b^{1/n})^m$, where $b^{1/n}$ means the positive $n^{th}$ root of $b$; $b^x$ is not yet defined for irrational $x$.

I know that the supremum and infimum both exist because if $b>1$ and $p<q$, then $b^p<b^q$. Also, by assuming that the inf $<$ sup, I got a contradiction. The part I'm stuck on is deriving a contradiction from assuming that sup $<$ inf. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: choose a rational number $p$ between sup and inf.

Comment: Assume sup<inf.I know that if there is a rational number $q$ such that $b^q=p$, where $p$ is between sup and inf, and $q<x$, then $b^q<p$. And if $q>x$, then $b^q>p$. So that would be my contradiction. I'm not sure if that's where your hint was meant to lead me, but how do I show that such a $q$ exists? I know I can take the logarithm, but how do I know that $log(p)/log(b)$ is rational?

Comment: You're right, my hint dealt with the "wrong level" in the problem and doesn't help that much. Try this one: let $S$ be the sup and $I$ be the inf. If $S<I$, then set $\epsilon = I-S$. Choose $p<x$ rational such that $b^p > S-\frac\epsilon{100}$ (say) and $q>x$ rational such that $b^q < I+\frac\epsilon{100}$. Then with $r=\frac12(p+Q)$, use some inequalities to show that $b^r>S$ and $b^r<I$, contradiction.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Actually I've run into a problem: I have the inequality $S-\frac\epsilon{100}<b^p<b^r<b^q<I+\frac\epsilon{100}$, and I'm trying to show that for all $n$, $S-\frac\epsilon{n}<b^r<I+\frac\epsilon{n}$. This would show that $S<b^r<I$. But $p$ and $q$ depend on $n$, and $r$, being their midpoint, depends on $p$ and $q$, and hence $n$. How do I proceed from here? That is, how do I show that $r$ doesn't change when $n$ changes?

Comment: Yes, I agree that your $r$ will be changing in that setup. The idea was that $b^p$ and $b^q$ would be so close to $S$ and $I$ that one could prove directly that $b^r$ was between $S$ and $I$. Since $r=\frac12(p+q)$ implies $b^r = \sqrt{b^pb^q}$, I now think a multiplicative scale will be better: set $\rho = I/S$, and choose $p<x$ so that $S/\rho < b^p < S$ and $q>x$ so that $I < b^q < I\rho$.